# Find the volume inside

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Find the volume inside the torus $\rho=\sin\phi$.

First of all how can $\rho=\sin\phi$ represent a torus? I can't even visualise that.

All Ideas are welcome, this looks like a 'food for thought problem' for everyone.

Comment: It's definitely not a [torus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html).

Comment: think of viewing the cross section in 2 dimensions and then use the curve to generate a volume of revolution.

Comment: it looks like a sphere of radius 1/2 centered at (0,0,1/2) in rectangular coordinates.

Comment: This refers to spherical coordinates in a highly nonstandard way. What is meant (see Shabbee's answer) is the rotational surface that in spherical coordinates with $\theta=0$ at the north pole can be expressed by the equation $r=\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

$r=\sin\theta$ is a torus in spherical coordinates with major radius of $R=0.5$ and minor radius  of $r=0.5$.
$$V=(\pi r^2)(2\pi R)=0.25\pi^2$$

[image]